# Interceptor break web service ssl connexion

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, ssl, glassfish, interceptor

I have an ejb endpoint webservice secured with ssl (glassfish 3.1.2 and jax-ws)
I'm logging users activties using an interceptor :

```
@Statless
public class WebServiceInterceptor {

    @Resource
    WebServiceContext wsContext;

    @AroundInvoke
    protected Object audit(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {



        MessageContext mc = wsContext.getMessageContext();


        try {
            Principal principal = wsContext.getUserPrincipal();
            user = principal.getName();
            System.out.println("user:" + user);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("log faild!");
        }
}
```

When the interceptor is triggred I get this Exception:

```
ATTENTION: invocation error on ejb endpoint Oculus_ws_v1 at /mywebservice/mywebservice : com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:130)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.encoding.LazyStreamCodec.encode(LazyStreamCodec.java:88)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:285)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.encodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:421)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$100(HttpAdapter.java:99)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:650)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:263)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:163)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.handlePost(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:120)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.invoke(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.EjbWebServiceServlet.dispatchToEjbEndpoint(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.EjbWebServiceServlet.service(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:131)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(ServletAdapter.java:1059)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter$FilterChainImpl.invokeFilterChain(ServletAdapter.java:999)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.doService(ServletAdapter.java:434)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.service(ServletAdapter.java:384)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:263)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamWriterFilter.flush(XMLStreamWriterFilter.java:71)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamWriterUtil.getOutputStream(XMLStreamWriterUtil.java:103)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.writePayloadTo(JAXBMessage.java:382)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.message.SOAPBody.writePayload(SOAPBody.java:132)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.message.SOAPBody.writeTo(SOAPBody.java:166)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.message.SecuredMessage.writeTo(SecuredMessage.java:364)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.message.MessageWrapper.writeTo(MessageWrapper.java:355)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:127)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: ClientAbortException:  java.io.IOException: SSLOutputWriter: CLOSED
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyOutputBuffer.doFlush(GrizzlyOutputBuffer.java:439)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyOutputBuffer.flush(GrizzlyOutputBuffer.java:405)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyOutputStream.flush(GrizzlyOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletOutputStreamImpl.flush(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:100)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:103)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:225)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:261)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: SSLOutputWriter: CLOSED
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.SSLOutputWriter.flushChannel(SSLOutputWriter.java:98)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ssl.SSLOutputBuffer.flushChannel(SSLOutputBuffer.java:138)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:498)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flush(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:476)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.action(ProcessorTask.java:1287)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ssl.SSLProcessorTask.action(SSLProcessorTask.java:164)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.Response.action(Response.java:268)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyOutputBuffer.doFlush(GrizzlyOutputBuffer.java:434)
    ... 48 more

INFO: user:super_hd
ATTENTION: invocation error on ejb endpoint Oculus_ws_v1 at /Oculus_ws_v1/Oculus_ws_v1 : com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:130)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.encoding.LazyStreamCodec.encode(LazyStreamCodec.java:88)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:285)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.encodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:421)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$100(HttpAdapter.java:99)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:650)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:263)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:163)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.handlePost(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:120)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.invoke(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.EjbWebServiceServlet.dispatchToEjbEndpoint(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.EjbWebServiceServlet.service(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:131)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(ServletAdapter.java:1059)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter$FilterChainImpl.invokeFilterChain(ServletAdapter.java:999)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.doService(ServletAdapter.java:434)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.service(ServletAdapter.java:384)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:263)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamWriterFilter.flush(XMLStreamWriterFilter.java:71)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamWriterUtil.getOutputStream(XMLStreamWriterUtil.java:103)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.writePayloadTo(JAXBMessage.java:382)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.message.SOAPBody.writePayload(SOAPBody.java:132)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.message.SOAPBody.writeTo(SOAPBody.java:166)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.message.SecuredMessage.writeTo(SecuredMessage.java:364)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.message.MessageWrapper.writeTo(MessageWrapper.java:355)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:127)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: ClientAbortException:  java.io.IOException: SSLOutputWriter: CLOSED
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyOutputBuffer.doFlush(GrizzlyOutputBuffer.java:439)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyOutputBuffer.flush(GrizzlyOutputBuffer.java:405)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyOutputStream.flush(GrizzlyOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletOutputStreamImpl.flush(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:100)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:103)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:225)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:261)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: SSLOutputWriter: CLOSED
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.SSLOutputWriter.flushChannel(SSLOutputWriter.java:98)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ssl.SSLOutputBuffer.flushChannel(SSLOutputBuffer.java:138)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:498)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flush(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:476)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.action(ProcessorTask.java:1287)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ssl.SSLProcessorTask.action(SSLProcessorTask.java:164)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.Response.action(Response.java:268)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyOutputBuffer.doFlush(GrizzlyOutputBuffer.java:434)
    ... 48 more
```

If I disable ssl ecnryption or comment `wsContext.getUserPrincipal();` everything run fine.
Thanks

Edit 1:
It apperas that this not related to thse use of interceptor , if I call this method :

```
  @Resource
    WebServiceContext wsContext;

    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
        System.out.println("ws context:" + wsContext.getUserPrincipal());

        return "Hello " + txt + " !";
    }
```

I get almost the same exception

```
ATTENTION: processorTask.exceptionSSLcert
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSLEngine is closing/closed
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.kickstartHandshake(SSLEngineImpl.java:656)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.beginHandshake(SSLEngineImpl.java:689)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.SSLUtils.doPeerCertificateChain(SSLUtils.java:563)
    at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.doPeerCertificateChain(SSLReadFilter.java:340)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ssl.SSLProcessorTask.action(SSLProcessorTask.java:153)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.Request.action(Request.java:430)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyRequest.getAttribute(GrizzlyRequest.java:835)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyRequest.getUserPrincipal(GrizzlyRequest.java:1845)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.HttpServletRequestImpl.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:906)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletConnectionImpl.getUserPrincipal(ServletConnectionImpl.java:219)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.AbstractWebServiceContext.getUserPrincipal(AbstractWebServiceContext.java:84)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.WebServiceContextImpl.getUserPrincipal(WebServiceContextImpl.java:112)
    at Ws.PocWS.hello(PocWS.java:32)
```

Any workaround will be nice .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparenlty this a weird but non buggy behaviour.

If you call getPrincipal() when you use an ssl/jax-ws encryption the container "switch" automatically to mutual ssl authentification . As a result this will break the whole thing because I didn't configure a keystore in client side.
A workaround can be found [here](http://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-1385)

Comment: Link is not found. Can you please update it. Have the same problem now :)